# Why do I get an uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null, when I run these two scripts in the same script file?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Both these scrips work with no errors when on their own. However, when they are within the same script file, script 2 will stop working. Can anybody help with why this happens please. Thank you.

Script 1:

```
var changeImage = (function() {

var index = 0;                                              
var image = [                                                     
"images/slideshow/img1.jpg", 
"images/slideshow/img2.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img3.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img4.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img5.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img6.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img7.jpg"
];

function slideShow() {

  var img = document.getElementById("slide");                   


  img.src = image[index];                                         

  if(index < image.length -1) {
    index++;                                                       
  } else { 
    index = 0;                                                    
  }
  setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);                                 
  }
slideShow();                                                      
}());
```

Script 2:

```
var galleryModel = (function() {

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');                    

var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('bolivian');          
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");              

  for(var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {                        
  gallery[i].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
  }

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];           

span.onclick = function() {                                       
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}());
```

**SOLVED**,
I have manged to solve this by changing the setTimeout to setInterval and calling the slideShow function correctly within script 1.

Script 1:

```
var changeImage = (function() {

var index = 0;                                              
var image = [                                                     
"images/slideshow/img1.jpg", 
"images/slideshow/img2.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img3.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img4.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img5.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img6.jpg",
"images/slideshow/img7.jpg"
];

function slideShow() {

  var img = document.getElementById("slide");                   


  img.src = image[index];                                         

    if(index < image.length -1) {
      index++;                                                       
    } else { 
      index = 0;                                                    
    }                               
  }
  setInterval(slideShow, 3000);                                                    
}());
```

Script 2:

```
var galleryModel = (function() {

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');                    

var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('bolivian');          
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");              

  for(var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {                        
  gallery[i].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
  }

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];           

span.onclick = function() {                                       
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}());
```

Comment: It's impossible to say from what's in the question, as the code is obviously incomplete (there's no closing `}` on the `slideShow` function, for instance), so... From what's there, no apparent conflicts, but... In any case, all those globals are a bad idea; wrap both of them in scoping functions.

Comment: Are you sure your 2nd script is working as per looking into it they not. setTimeout expect an function not a name of function as string

Comment: What happens when you put them both in the same file? Is there an error?

Comment: I have wrapped them in their own IIFE and I still get the same problem. Where one stops working when they are in the same file.

Comment: @James Which functionality exactly does stop working? Do you get any exceptions? Can you post a sample markup of the page this runs in? Are you trying to manipulate the same `<img>` element as both a slideshow and gallery?

Comment: @Bergi, no I am not manipulating the same <img> , these are different galleries.  Depending which I put first in order, the second one stops functioning.  So as of the order above script 2 stops working with a error of span.onclick function undefined?.  But works when you delete script 1 from the file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact and complete error message.

Comment: @front_end_dev, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  However, I still needed to change the setTimeout to setInterval for the function to work correctly.